# Order of rectangles to display and can they be changed?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I working on a project in which I have to simulate a memory manager and show some memory snapshots. I have created a draw class via examples I have found here in which I override the paintComponet(). Everything draws fine.

I would like to be able to draw a rectangle to represent a memory partition and then overlay another rectangle over top to represent an incoming job (ie Job1 is in this partition3). What seems to occur is that I add the partition first (which will always be the case) and then when I add the job it will sit behind the partition block. Is there a way other than drawing the Job first to shift these after the job is created?

Here is the paint override

```
@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    // set up rendering to allow anti-aliasing
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // create the rectangle to represent the memory partition block 
    //  x = address position h = amount of memory (y & w are predefined for the display block)

      Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);    // create the rectangle 
    g2d.setPaint(partColor);                // set it's color
    g2d.fill(rect);                 // fill it in

    // create the transparency for the text
     Composite comp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .4f);
     g2d.setComposite(comp);

     // draw the text with color, type and size and center the text in the block created above
     g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
     g2d.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
     g2d.drawString(text, (int)((w / 2) - (text.length()/2)), (int)h/2);

}
```

The call to draw is in my window class (this will place the partition in front of the job) but I need to order to be reversed without changing the order of the calls.

```
    // Draw both Text and Block with transparency
    DrawPartition part1 = new DrawPartition(Color.blue, 0, 0, 110, 100, "part1");
    part1.setBounds(5, 5, 110, 100);
    snapPanel.add(part1);

    DrawJob job1 = new DrawJob(Color.green, 0, 0, 110, 100, "Job 1");
    job1.setBounds(5, 15, 110, 100);
    snapPanel.add(job1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't do this?

```
// Draw both Text and Block with transparency
DrawPartition part1 = new DrawPartition(Color.blue, 0, 0, 110, 100, "part1");
part1.setBounds(5, 5, 110, 100);

DrawJob job1 = new DrawJob(Color.green, 0, 0, 110, 100, "Job 1");
job1.setBounds(5, 15, 110, 100);
snapPanel.add(job1);

snapPanel.add(part1);
```

A more general answer would be to add a z component to each of your rectangles.  Then you can loop through your rectangles in the paintComponent method, drawing them in z order.

Comment: Gilbert, the problem is that the partitions get drawn when a memory scheme is selected and are displayed (in the case of say a fixed memory partition scheme). The jobs will then be created and distroyed later to simulate the processing in and out of a JobQueue.

Comment: @jbolt: Separate the creation of the rectangles from the drawing of the rectangles.  Create the partition rectangles, then create and destroy the job rectangles over time.  In paintComponent, you clear the drawing area, draw the partition rectangles, then draw the job rectangles.

Comment: I will play around with it for a while to see what I can come up with. It is a step in the right direction. Would a good appraoch be to create these objects and store them in a array list[][]. In that way I could add objects in the order they should appear (Job1, Part3, Job2, Part5) and then create a loop to display then in the snapshot panel whenerver I add to the list?

Comment: @jbolt: That's the right idea.  I'd use two ArrayLists, one for the partition rectangles and one for the job rectangles.  In paintComponent, you'd have two drawing loops, one for the partition rectangles and one for the job rectangles.

Comment: Maybe I'm not picturing this right... and I and having an issue getting these to show in the snapshot panel. If I create the Job object from within the window constructor and call snapPanel.add(Job) they show up fine, but when I call this from another class called FixedPartition() in which I create the partitions containing the partitions address, size and status(free or busy), I was also trying to create and display these blocks in the snapshot panel. I make the object as above, call part.setBounds(boundInfo), and then call mw.snapPanel.add(object). Would this diplay correctly?

Comment: @jbolt: I have no idea what Swing parts your classes create.  You're creating an animation, if I understand you correctly.  I would have one JPanel where I override the paintComponent.  In the paintComponent, I would draw the rectangles using the drawRect (or fillRect) methods of the Graphics class.  I would first draw the partition rectangles, then draw the job rectangles.  There would be no other Swing components except for the one JPanel.  There would be no add methods called.

Comment: I will work on this a while to see what I can come up with. I will let you know if I have any success.